# How do I turn on the camera?

Tags: pokemon-go

After I began Pokemon go, I clicked "no" if you want the camera to be on. I don't want to make a new account to activate it, so is there anyway to activate it after initially declining to use it? If not, should I make a new account?

Comment: Also note that you can't catch pokemons with camera on if your smartphone doesn't have compas. I'm not sure why, because if they mean they can't track your orientation in real-time with only GPS, then they should not be able to track exact position (distance to pokemon) too.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a switch labeled "AR" in the top right corner of the screen when catching Pokemon.  Turn that switch on to use the camera.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the AR option to use the camera, go to:
`Home > Settings App > Pokemon Go` (usually at the bottom) and slide the switch tagged Camera from grey to green, close Pokemon GO from recently opened apps and open Pokemon GO back up.